# Capitalize initial letter with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, capitalize

I know there's a filter in AngularJS to uppercase, but I want to make a function to capitalize only the initial letters of a full name, but with some restrictions. Prepositions ("da, de, di, do, du, das, des, dis, dos, dus") should be lower case.

Ex:

- josé Da silva -> José da Silva
- joão dos santos -> João dos Santos

Is there a efficient way to do this?

Comment: You will need to create your own filter.

Comment: Try something, and if you're stuck, then ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a custom filter for this:

```
.filter("name", function() {
    var ignoreWords = ["da", "de", "di", "do", "du", "das", "des", "dis", "dos", "dus"]
    return function(name) {
      return name.split(" ").map(function(word) {
        if (ignoreWords.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          return word[0].toLowerCase() + word.substr(1);
        } else {
          return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
        }
    }).join(" ")
  }
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xw1vrASJEP4VU53HFs8v?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, man. Really helpful, but I forgot to mention I want to capitalize on "ng-change", for example: after the field lost the focus, it will call the filter, understand me?

Comment: @developer033 - Then make this a `$scope` function - call it on `ngBlur` and pass the word in.

Comment: I did, but I can't get all the name, here is  the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/5strtxwximgRMMlPfLe8?p=preview, can you help me?

Comment: @developer033 - http://plnkr.co/edit/E5rleNrZvvbT8nWP8bSB?p=preview - don't use `getElementById` with Angular like you were - use `$scope` variables.

Comment: **Edit**: Found a little bug: Ex: JOSE DA SILVA, it just transform to JOSE dA SILVA, not put uppercase the normal words, nor lowercase the prepositions.